# Criteria to choose between EER and UML

Tags: database-design, uml, eer-model, entity-relationship

What criteria should I use to choose between EER and UML Class Diagram to model user requirements for a large database application? What are the advantages or disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it doesn't matter, both can be used to model databses